# How to grab only latest update record from data table in Laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have following table name as projects like this structure,

```
id    name    adtype created_at    updated_at
1     gobba     1      2018-02-25    2018-02-25
2     manna     0      2018-04-25    2018-04-25
3     alaya     1      2017-12-28    2017-12-28
```

I need grab only one result witch related to latest updated record and adtype == 1, I code following controller, for this,

```
 public function showad()
     {
 $projects = Vehicle::with('uploads')
            ->where('adtype','=',1)
            ->latest('updated_at');
return view('vehicles.slider')->withProjects($projects);
```

but this working but not filtering latest updated records. how can correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`:

```
$projects = Vehicle::with('uploads')
    ->where('adtype', '=', 1)
    ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
    ->take(1)
    ->get();
```

This should correspond to the following raw MySQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM uploads
WHERE adtype = 1
ORDER BY updated_at DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: ...which is what my answer should be doing.